# Facebook Graph API get user id of comments on page in development mode

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, comments

I am trying to get the id of people who commented on a particular post on a page. I am currently on development mode and have not gotten my app approved.

From the documentation, the `from` field in the comment edge should return me the id of the person who made the comment. I am calling this endpoint using page access token.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v8.0/2760653923985966_2772526242798734?fields=from
    
params = {
    'access_token' : 'page_access_token'
}

requests.get(url=url, params=params)
```

but this is the response i am getting

> {'id': '2760653923985966_2772526242798734'}

Which is just the id of the comment. I have tried without the field but the response remain same. What am I doing wrong ?

Is it because my app is still in development and I haven't submitted it for approval?

Similarly if I try to call the `reactions` edge on the post I also get a blank response. Does this mean I cannot get user ids who liked or commented on my pages post without getting my app approved ?

Comment: Try with a comment / reaction made by a user that has a role in your app.

Comment: So if I comment as the page. Then there is a from field in the comments, with name and id. If i comment from my own id (who is admin of the page) then there is no from field

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution? I have the same issue.

Comment: @Roshan basically if you are in development mode, you do not have access to ids of profiles other than your own. So there is no way. You need approval to get these values

Comment: @HassanJalil no, I'm on live mode but still I have this issue that I can't get the 'from' attribute in comments.

Comment: Hi. Did anyone manage to find the problem?

Comment: So from my understanding, in development mode, you cant get ids of profiles you dont own.

Comment: Did anyone find a solution for that problem beside the accepted answer down below?

Answer (score 1):

in the new facebook API, you'll need Business verification to access the user-id that's not yours and they'll monitor how much you use.

Comment: I have a business verification and still got no 'from' field for comments of strangers.